# How do I correctly implement the 'isDelete' method?

Tags: apex, trigger, delete

This is the code I am trying to use. I will also add that in the parameters of the trigger, I have added the 'before delete' and 'after delete' at the top of the trigger.

[image]

And I am getting the following error. This only pops up when trying to use the trigger and is not permission related (i.e I can modify/delete records).

[image]

Any help would really be appreciated, I am new to Apex and have only been writing in it for about 2 months, so so don't roast my subpar, crappy code haha :)

p.s feel free to criticise any other things you would do differently too, I'll defo take them into consideration

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stock Exchange (SFSE)! Excellent job being open to constructive ciriticism in order to grow your knowledge and improve your code. A suggestion/request regarding SFSE: for posting code (and most anything that has text) please either instead of a screenshot, or in addition to a screenshot, copy/paste the text into your question or answer. An image of text with no accompanying actual text is not good accessibility-wise for folks with screen readers. Plus it makes it harder for anyone to help if they want to copy your code and put it in a sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely getting a `NullPointerException`. Do not use `.equals` unless you know a variable is not null first, and ideally, never use it at all. You can use `==` instead, which is null-safe.

In addition, some general notes:

You should be using an [Aggregate-Query-Update pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) to make sure your trigger can handle data in bulk deletes correctly.

You can use a Set to simplify your check:

```
Set<String> valuesToCheck = new Set<String> { '6513','8111','8391'... };
// some time later ...
if(valuesToCheck.contains(mid.MCC__c)) {
  // Do stuff here
}
```

You might also consider using Custom Metadata, a Custom Setting, or even a Custom Label so you can make changes to these values without having to change/deploy code in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response!